# How to use the or statement (||) correctly, in an else-if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

Consider this code:

```
string GameExit;
bool GameChoiceGo = true;

while (GameChoiceGo == true)
{
    system("cls"); 
    cout << "\n  Are you sure you want to exit? (Yes or No)     ";
    cin >>  GameExit;
    if (GameExit == "y" || "Y" || "yes" || "Yes" || "YES")
    {
        cout << "User typed Yes";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
        break;
    }
    if (GameExit == "n" || "N" || "no" || "No" || "NO")
    {
        cout << "User typed No";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
        GameChoiceGo = false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nI'm sorry but, " << GameExit << " is not a acceptable choice. Type: Yes or No.\n\n\n";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
    }
}
break;
```

Here, only the first statement is activated. Even if the user types `"No"` or anything else, it will output `"user typed yes"`.

The `else-if statements` work if I replace the `or statements` with only one statement (i.e. `"y"` and `"n"`). The only problem is, I want to have any possible version of yes and no that the user might type in the code.

Any ideas why the code is not working correctly?

Comment: You forgot an `else` for the no branch of you if statement.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: Terminology issues: `||` is an *operator*, and `x || y` is an *or-expression*, not a *statement*. Also, it's an *if-else-statement*, not an *else-if-statement*. (This may seem nitpicky, but the code sequence `else if` is not special.)

Comment: I wish it worked like that...imagine the extra characters I wouldn't have to type...or copy paste.

Comment: It's a shame we don't have a canonical dupe for that common beginner's mistake.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit: I'm not using a book. I do have some books for reference, but I purchased a subscription to Pluralsight. I actually haven't gotten to the or statements in my Pluralsight lessons yet, but I was making a test program and decided to try them on my own.

Comment: I recommend studying (at least basics of) propositional logic: http://www.iep.utm.edu/prop-log/ That will make it easier to understand boolean expressions.

Comment: Sebastian Redl: I appreciate you correcting me on that. I used to write a little Java (along with some dedicated languages), where it is called else-if and not if-else; my mistake. Also, I will try to use the phrase or-expression from now on. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way using OR operator in "your" code is as below (note the explicit use of `==` statements between `||` operators):

```
    if (GameExit == "y" || GameExit =="Y" || GameExit =="yes" || GameExit =="Yes" || GameExit =="YES")
    {
        cout << "User typed Yes";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
        break;
    }
    if (GameExit == "n" || GameExit =="N" || GameExit =="no" || GameExit =="No" || GameExit =="NO")
    {
        cout << "User typed No";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
        GameChoiceGo = false;
    }
```

PS: The above answer is not intended to give the best programming practice in a similar situation but to give the specific answer to the OP with the minimal code change :)

```
// -----
```

EDIT: Here is a better approach using STL. Note that (unsorted) array lookup requires linear search, whereas `unordered_set`, which is a hash set, has (on average) constant time lookup. This will be faster especially when the yes, no etc. options are plenty.

```
    #include <unordered_set>

    ...
    // These sets can be as large as possible or even dynamically 
    //  updated while the program is running. insert, remove, lookup will
    // all be much faster than a simple array.
    unordered_set<string> ySet{"y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "YES"};
    unordered_set<string> nSet{"n", "N", "no", "No", "NO"};

    if (ySet.find(GameExit) != ySet.end())
    {
        cout << "User typed Yes";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
        break;
    }
    if (nSet.find(GameExit) != nSet.end())
    {
        cout << "User typed No";
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
        GameChoiceGo = false;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem. I knew it was going to be a simple answer, I cannot believe I didn't think of that. I appreciate the instant answer!

Comment: @StephenR.Hayes -- Note that the answer is hard-coded to only those values of "yes" and "no".  If you're in a situation where there are many values for "yes/no" (do you really want an endless string of `||` conditions?), or the "yes/no" values are in some way custom (for example, foreign language), then the other solutions using `array` and containers may be more suitable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Good comment! Just a minor addition, when there are many possible values for each option, the use of hashset can be faster than an array. Constant time vs linear (or logarithmic if sorted array) time complexity. There might be cases that the options are dynamically added and/or removed.

Answer (score 8):

I'm sorry, but you have to write `GameExit ==` for every condition you want to check:

```
if (GameExit == "y" || GameExit == "Y" || GameExit == "yes" || GameExit == "Yes" || GameExit == "YES")
```

If you write `if ("y")` (which is basically what you are doing, only with more statements), the `const char[]` will decay to a `const char*`, and that pointer will be compared to `0`. Now, that pointer will *never* be null, as there will always be memory allocated for the string literal.

A better solution is to (1) make an array with all the options, so that checking the conditions becomes a simple search or (2) convert the input to all lowercase for example, and compare that.

```
// 1)
std::vector<std::string> options = { "y", "Y", "yes", "Yes", "YES" };

if (std::find(options.begin(), options.end(), GameExit) != options.end());
// or
if (std::any_of(options.begin(), options.end(), [&GameExit](const auto& value) { 
        return GameExit == value;
   }); 

// 2)
std::transform(GameExit.begin(), GameExit.end(), GameExit.begin(), ::tolower);

if (GameExit == "y" || GameExit == "yes");
```

You can look up the functions if you do not know what they do :).

Comment: Slight improvement is to use `std::any_of` instead of `find`

Comment: Praetorian: What is the difference between "find" and "any_of"?

Comment: @Praetorian True, but it would expand the `if` statement a bit too much IMO. Still added though, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I wish there was a `std::any_of_equal` similar to the Boost version.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a complete equality for each expression like this:

```
if ( gameExit == "y" || gameExit == "Y" ) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GameExit == "y" || "Y" || ....
```

is incorrect. The correct method is:

```
GameExit == "y" || GameExit == "Y" || ....
```

and so on, both for the yes or no case.

Comment: I appreciate the instant answer! Thank you very much! This fixed my problem. I was using the syntax of some of the other programming languages while trying to write the or statements. I like C++'s way better because it is more structured!